# The application and the screen stop when running the code

Tags: kotlin, python-3.6, chaquopy

I am a beginner in programming, and I found it difficult to overcome this problem, which is represented in the Android application that runs the Python code

The code works fine. But when I add while Ture, the screen stops. What is the cause of the problem? Thank you
script python

Is there a suggestion about this problem?

def main(CodeAreaData):

```
file_dir = str(Python.getPlatform().getApplication().getFilesDir())



filename = join(dirname(file_dir), 'file.txt')



try:
   

    original_stdout = sys.stdout

   
    sys.stdout = open(filename, 'w', encoding = 'utf8', errors="ignore")

    

    exec(CodeAreaData) # it will execute our code and save output in file

    

    

    sys.stdout.close()

   

    sys.stdout = original_stdout

   
    output = open(filename, 'r').read()
   
    sys.stdout.close()
except Exception as e:

    

    sys.stdout = original_stdout

    

    output = e


return str(output)
```

````
my code kotlin
```kotlin

val py = Python.getInstance()

//here we call our script with the name "myscirpt

//here we call our script with the name "myscirpt
val pyobj = py.getModule("myscript") //give python script name


//and call main method inside script...//pass data here

//and call main method inside script...//pass data here
val obj = pyobj.callAttr("main", editor.text.toString())
println(obj)
````

Answer (score 1):

If you're adding a while true statement, then the screen should stop. That will lead to an infinite loop. A while loop runs until the condition evaluates to false. Here is more info about that:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-while-true-in-python/

Comment: I think you've included the wrong link.

Comment: @mhsmith good catch, it's been fixed